# Display the most accurate time possible

Tags: linux, ntp

I want to set the time on my watch as closest as possible to the actual, synchronized, current time.

Is there a command which will repeatedly display the current time down to the second, calibrated using NTP, so I can set my watch properly?

Comment: date in a system running ntpd? I do not get it, really.

Comment: If you have NTP running, you could use `while true; do sleep .5; date; done` or similar. But it's probably easier to go to http://www.time.gov/ or another such site.

Comment: `ntp` is capable of accuracy in the microsecond range. If you're going to set your watch by eye then pretty much any time source would be sufficient.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Will `date` on a system running `ntpd` ensure that my date is synced properly?

Comment: Obviously a web page is easier. We could argue that it will be off for the time it takes to load, however it is mostly an academic observation.

Answer (score 2):

If your system is sync'd with ntp (check `ntpq -crv` for "sync_ntp" in the status and/or `/usr/sbin/ntptime` for code "0 (OK)" and PLL or FLL but not UNSYNC for status) then `date` and friends all return accurate time, estimated to be off by the "offset" value (which is typically several ms, far better than you'll ever set your watch)

I used to use a perl script like this to set my watch, before I had one that set itself:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8;

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday usleep);
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

# Set up start conditions
my ($timer, $residual) = gettimeofday;
usleep(1e6 - $residual);
$residual = 0;
++$timer;
my $correction = 0;

while (1) {
        usleep(1e6 + $residual + $correction);
        ++$timer;
        my ($m_s, $m_µs) = gettimeofday;
        $correction = (1e6*($timer - $m_s) - $m_µs);
        $residual += $correction;

        if ($correction < 5_000 && $correction > -5_000) {
                # if within 5ms
                print "\a  ".localtime($timer)."\t${correction} µs\n";
        } else {
                print "x ".localtime($timer)."\t${correction} µs\n";
        }

}
```

Run it in a terminal. It tries to display the time every second, along with emitting a terminal beep if it hit it within 5ms. Of course, truth be told, latency to produce the beep is probably more than 5ms, as is the time it takes your brain to recognize and respond to the beep.

(I suppose you could add in something where the computer first tested your reaction time by having you press a key when you hear the beep, and then used that to sound the beep a little early to cancel out your reaction time.)

Comment: This is... EPIC.

Comment: Epic? LOL. I have no idea what the purpose of the bell is but it took me longer to read your perl script than it did to double check two man pages and type `$ nice -n 1 watch -b -p -n1 "date  +%s.%N;false"`

Comment: @dfc the bell is because I found it much easier to press the zero seconds button on my watch in response to a sound than a new line appearing in a terminal. Also, auditory reaction time is less than visual.

Comment: @dfc it's nice to see watch -p getting some use  but also I think that won't sync to the second boundary. If you start it at 0.4s past the boundary, it'll make an effort to stay there. Not so good for setting a watch. (Given, I haven't actually tested that, so maybe I'm remembering wrong).

Answer (score 0):

ntpd is supposed to keep up with the word wide infra-structure of NTP servers, and it has algorithms for compensating/calculate/take in account the loss/RTT of the UDP packets through the Internet and propagating the time through the strata. stratum 1 NTP servers are typically connected to atomic clocks. date is more than enough for a resolution of 1.